# why is int ** x not the same as int x[][]?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, syntax-error

This may be a dumb question but I don't understand why do I get this error :

```
void func (int ** array) { }
 
int main (void) {
    int array[5][5] = { };
    func(array);
}


 warning: passing argument 1 of 'func' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      func(array);
           ^~~~~
    note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[5]'
     void func (int ** array) { }
            ~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Comment: You might like section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/): in short: arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays.

Comment: Also, `int ** array` in the function will have no idea of the width of each row of `int array[5][5]`.

Comment: why does it needs the width ?

Comment: Because in order to access `array[3][2]`, the processor needs to compute `(3*width + 2) * sizeof(int)`. If you declare the function as `void func(int (*array)[5])`, then the compiler has the information it needs to do the calculation. If the compiler supports [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), you could declare the function as `void func(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols])`. That would allow the code to work with any size array.

Comment: First of all: Welcome to SO! To your issue: Maybe `typedef` can make it better readable. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `int **` type means a double pointer to an `int`, but you have an array of pointers here. Your function declaration should therefore be

```c
    void func (int (*array)[]) { }
```

The internal functionality of a double pointer to an `int` can be represented as follows:

```
+-------+     +------+     +-----+
| int** | --> | int* | --> | int |
+-------+     +------+     +-----+
```

Each square should represent a memory location, with the type in it. In contrast, the representation of `int (*array)[]` would be the following:

```
                      +-------------+
array ->  array[0] -> | array[0][0] |
                      +-------------+
                      | array[0][1] |
                      +-------------+
                      |     ...     |
                      +-------------+
          array[1] -> | array[1][0] |
                      +-------------+
                            ...
```

Each square shows how the corresponding value can be accessed. Note that only the values on the far right are in memory. Pointers are not required here, since the address of an array element can be calculated directly. Therefore

```c
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); // Outputs 25
```

indicates that memory space has been reserved for 25 values. So internally it's the same as declaring `int array[25]`, but with a different type and and access to array elements.

Comment: Ok but why is an array of pointers different from a pointer to a pointer ? because an array is a paointer

Comment: I mean what is the difference at a lower level between int ** a and int a [][] ?

Comment: @moutonlapin28 *because an array is a pointer*  No. NO! ***NO!***  An array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array.  A pointer is a variable that **holds** an address, and that address might even refer to something useful.  An array is a chunk of memory that **exists** so it **has** an address.  Arrays are passed to functions by the address of the first element.  Which in something like `int array[5][5]` is an `int (*)[5]` or a pointer to an array of 5 `int` values.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes to clarify some things:

- Even if pointers and arrays can often be used the same way and seem to be the same they are actually different.
- An array specifies storage (ignoring incomplete array like e.g. `a[]` here but they still need storage defined somewhere else).
- A pointer does not define storage (it is pointing to).
- An array name in an expression is treated by the compiler as pointer to the first element.
- The same for an array name in the declaration of a function parameter.
- A subscript is always equivalent to an offset to a pointer.
- On argument passing to function an implicit casting may happen (keep that in mind) but sometimes this is failing and that's what the compiler is saying (`int **` != `int *[]`). **You could do explicit casting** but that would be nasty and requires careful programming. Better fix function prototype.

With `int **array` you just define a handle (pointer to a pointer) to an `int`. But as the compiler says you are passing `int *array[5]` which is an array of 5 pointers to int. You need to change the function declaration to pass a pointer to an array of int. Because otherwise `func` would not be able to access elements of that array you passed.

That means:
When "building" the declaration of the tyoe you have at first stage an array `int array[]` and that needs to be changed at second stage to be a pointer to that array: `int ...  *array   ... []` (can't explain better without drawing) which will finally be `int (*array)[]`.

**If it helps to clarify then use `typedef`:**

```
typedef int (*ah)[];
void func (ah x) { }
```

Or (better):

```
typedef int a[];
void func (a *x) { }
```

Here you can clearly see which type of pointer `x` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function `void foo(int **p)`. The `p` it is given contains some address. At that address, there is an `int *`. If `foo` loads the data from that address and uses it as an address for a load, it will load an `int`.

Now consider an array `int a[5][5]`. Suppose we take the address of this array (or, somewhat equivalent, the address of its first element) and pass it to `foo`. Then `foo` has a `p` that contains the address of `a`. At that address, there is no `int *`. At that address, there are 25 `int` values, arranged in 5 groups of 5.

So, an `int [5][5]` is not an `int **`. And the address of its first element is not an `int **`, nor is its first element an `int *`.

That is why you cannot pass an `int [][]` in place of an `int **`.

In contrast, consider a function `void foo(int *p)`. The `p` this function is given contains some address. At that address, there is an `int`. If we have an array `int a[5]`, and we pass the address of its first element to `foo`, then `foo` receives a `p` that contains the address of an `int`. Thus, an `int []` that has been converted to the address of its first element is an `int *`.

These automatic array conversions work **only** on the first dimension of an array. If you have an `int a[5][6][7]`, the automatic conversion to its first element gives you a pointer to an `int [6][7]`, which is an `int (*)[6][7]`. The pointer points to groups of integers in memory. It does not point to a pointer.

Automatic conversion of an array to a pointer does not change what is actually in memory. So it cannot change the type of the thing that is pointed to: We can point to the `int` in an `int [][]`, but we cannot point to pointers to them because there are no such pointers in memory.

Comment: So if i understood correctly : int x[5][5] is not an array of 5 pointers each pointing to 5 ints but an array of 25 ints ?

Comment: with `int x[5][5];` you have `x` is an array of 5 "things", ie: `x[0]` is one of those "things", `x[1]` is another of those "things", etc. Each "thing" is an array of 5 `int`s. So you have an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

**If this is a part of a declaration:**

```
type **var;
```

would mean by a pointer to a pointer, that is, a variable that can hold address of another variable, which is also a pointer to the `var` of the type `type`.

But not with this case:

```
type *var[N];
```

This one states to the compiler that this is a pointer to the variable `var` of `N` contained array elements.

**As a type of dereference:**

`**var` is double dereference. Only if variable is an address of an address, the resulting expression will be the lvalue at the address stored in `*var` of type `type`.

---

You're trying to pass a *pointer to a pointer* type to *pointer to an array* type accepted by the function `func()`. That's the reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type “N-element array of `T`” will be converted (“decay”) an expression of type “pointer to `T`” and the value of the expression will be the first element of the array.

When you pass the *expression* `array` to `func`, it “decays” from type “5-element array of 5-element array `int`” to “pointer to 5-element array of `int`” (`int (*)[5]`).  So your function prototype needs to be

```
void func( int (*array)[5] )
```

You would index into this the same as any 2D array.

**Edit**

From the comments:

> But what is the difference at a low level ?

The structure of the memory is different.  A true 2D array has all its rows laid out contiguously and all rows have the same number of elements.  Given the definition

```
int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

it’s laid out in memory like so (addresses are just for illustration’s sake):

```
   +–––+
   | 1 | a[0][0] (0x8000)
   + – + 
   | 2 | a[0][1] (0x8004)
   +–––+
   | 3 | a[1][0] (0x8008)
   + - +
   | 4 | a[1][1] (0x800C)
   +–––+
```

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account - given a pointer `p` the expression `p + 1` yields the address of the next object of the pointed-to type, not the next byte.

This is how array subscripting works - the expression `a[i]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a + i)`.  Given a starting address `a`, offset `i` elements from that address and dereference the result.  In the case where `a` refers to an array, it “decays” to a pointer to the first element.

When we write

```
x = a[1][1];
```

the expression `a` “decays” to type `int (*)[2]` and its value is the address of the first element of `a` (`0x8000`).  `a[1]` is evaluated as `*(a + 1)`.  `a + 1` yields the address of the second *2-element array of `int`* (`0x8008`) following `a`.

Since the expression `a` has type `int (*)[2]`, the expression `*a` has type `int [2]`.  Since `*a == *(a + 0)`, the expression `a[0]` has type `int [2]`, and by extension any `a[i]` has type `int [2]`.

Since the expression `a[1]` has type `int [2]`, it decays to type `int *`, and its value is the address of the first element of `a[1]` (`0x8008`).  `a[1][1]` is evaluated as `*(a[1] + 1)`.  `a[1] + 1` yields the address of the second `int` object following `a[1]`.

An `int **` OTOH is typically used to implement a structure that looks like this:

```
   int **            int *               int
   +–––+             +–––+               +–––+
a: | +-+–––––> a[0]: | +-+––––> a[0][0]: | 1 | 
   +–––+             +–––+               +–––+
               a[1]: | +–+––+   a[0][1]: | 2 | 
                     +-––+  |            +–––+
                            |             ...
                            |            +–––+
                            +–> a[1][0]: | 3 | 
                                         +–––+
                                a[1][1]: | 4 | 
                                         +–––+
```

The "rows" of the array are not contiguous in memory, and they don’t even have to be the same length.  Such a structure is typically allocated as

```
int **a = malloc( sizeof *a * 2 );
if ( a )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  {
    a[i] = malloc( sizeof *a[i] * 2 );
    if ( a[i] )
    {
      a[i][0] = 2 * i;
      a[i][1] = 2 * i + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `a` is explicitly a pointer and each `a[i]` is explicitly a pointer.  There’s no implicit conversion from an array type to a pointer type.  You can index into this structure using the same notation as for a 2D array, but the underlying structure is completely different.

Comment: But what is the difference at a low level ?

Comment: It is posible to access any value with just the double pointer : if we have int ** x, and we need x[3][4], we go to *x (an array of addresses), we do +3 so we it means *(x + 3), then we go to *(*(x + 3)), an array of ints, we do + 4, *(*(x + 3) + 4) and we have the int we wanted.